# JavaScript if statement scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question about why this code is not working. I have a feeling it may have to do with variable scope but I can't pinpoint what is wrong. I can get the div id to print to the console, but I get an error saying that the id attr is undefined inside of the statement.

```
var game = {

    currentPlayerTurn: players.firstPlayer.token,   

    displayToken: function() {
        $('.unit').click(function() {
            if(game.currentPlayerTurn === 'X' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("X");
                game.currentPlayerTurn = players.secondPlayer.token;
            } else if(game.currentPlayerTurn === 'O' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("O");
                game.currentPlayerTurn = players.firstPlayer.token;
            }
            game.win($(this));
        })
    },

    win: function(div) {
        game.winCombos.forEach(function(element) {
            element.forEach(function(smell){ 
                if(smell === div.attr('id')) {
                    smell = game.currentPlayerTurn;
                }
            })})
        console.log(div.attr('id'));
    },



    winCombos: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]


};

 game.win();
```

Comment: That seems unlikely, the `div` argument should be available? Is this the entire code

Comment: is div a jquery object with at least one matching element?

Comment: @adeneo - I think the result of div.attr('id') is "undefined" - which would be the case if div is an empty jquery result ... or the first element in div jquery object has no id

Comment: `console.log($(div).attr('id'));`

Comment: of course, what I said wouldn't result in an error ... so, perhaps if the OP showed how the function is called

Comment: @JaromandaX -  the OP claims it works in the console.log, and there's nothing in the code that would prevent it from working inside the loops ?

Comment: @adeno - I read that, but he didn't state how he does it in the console - chances are though, that he's running this code before the target div is loaded in the DOM ... maybe a `$(function() { code goes here });` wrap is required to wait for DOM load

Answer (score 0):

`game.win();` is not being called with a page element. You'll need to give it something.

Example:

```
<div id="game"></div>

game.win($("#game"));
```